# Convert LitJson to Newtonsoft Json for run at IOS device Unity C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, litjson

How to convert the LitJson Json To NewtonSoft Json in unity c# ?

Example :

**In LitJson**

```
JsonData CJsonData;
cJsonData = JsonMapper.ToObject(www.downloadHandler.text);
Debug.log(cJsonData["reason"].ToString();
```

// This cJsonData can contain a nested array.

**How the code look like in a Newtonsoft Json for ios ?**

I dont want to create a class property because the return from www.donwloadHandler.text could be different. It is depend on the return.
When using LitJson with datatype JsonData and use JsonMapper.Tobject i could easily get the data without need any more code.

*

> In LitJson we have DataType JsonData which is automatic convert it to
>   an associated array from Mapper.

*

*I want i can get the data like LitJson*

**Debug.log(cJsonData["reason"].ToString();**

Or Maybe

**Debug.log(cJsonData["reason"]["abc"].ToString();**

Or Maybe

**Debug.log(cJsonData["reason"]["cc"]["aaa"].ToString();**

But in newtonsoft json we must add a class to deserializeobject.

**In newtonsoft json :**

```
someclass Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someclass>(www.donwloadHandler.text);
```

This i dont want. Because we need to add someclass

and this :

```
string data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(www.downloadHanlder.text);
```

This also i dont want. Because it is string not an associated array like litjson.

Is that clear ?

Thank You

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after. Is this just asking how to get a json field using newtonsoft?

Comment: @Ben i want the same result in newtonsoft json from my litjson example above ? How the code looks like in newtonsoft json ?

Comment: @Ben please look the question again. I have edited the questeion with more detail explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much the same. No need to deserialise to read the data, just use a JObject:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
            {
              ""CPU"": ""Intel"",
              ""Integrated Graphics"": true,
              ""USB Ports"": 6,
              ""OS Version"": 7.1,
              ""Drives"": [
                ""DVD read/writer"",
                ""500 gigabyte hard drive""
              ],
              ""ExtraData"" : {""Type"": ""Mighty""}
            }";

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

        Console.WriteLine(o["CPU"]);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(o["Drives"]);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(o["ExtraData"]["Type"]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```